# assign public function to a variable

Tags: php, function, class, public

How can I assign a public function to a PHP variable, i have this class:

```
class FajrfilesExecution {

    public function fajrExecution($id=null){
       $arr = [
                [4]=>[
                       'name'=>'ali',
                      ],
                [8]=>[
                       'name'=>'mos',
                      ],
                [5]=>[
                       'name'=>'heliya',
                      ],
              ];
       return $arr[$id]['name'];
    }
}
```

and somewhere else i should use this public function several times:

```
<div id = <?= FajrfilesExecution::fajrExecution(4)  ?>>
         <div id = <?= FajrfilesExecution::fajrExecution(8)  ?>>
  .....
```

how can i assign this public function to a variable and use it. something like this :

```
<?php  $a = FajrfilesExecution::fajrExecution()?>

<div id = <?= $a(4)  ?>>
         <div id = <?= $a(2)  ?>>
  .....
```

Comment: _how can i assign this public function to a variable and use it. something like this_ You already did, didn't you?

Comment: var_dump($a[0]);die;
already NULL

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few minor syntax errors - I've amended your code below.

```
class FajrfilesExecution {
    public static function fajrExecution($id=null){
        $arr = ['a','b','c'];
        return $arr;
    }
}

$a = FajrfilesExecution::fajrExecution();
?>

<div id="<?php echo $a[0]; ?>">
<div id="<?php echo $a[2]; ?>">
```

- `return $arr[];` doesn't return the array. You just want `$return $arr;`
- You didn't call `echo` to display your output. `<?php $a[0] ?>` on its own doesn't do anything. You can also use `<?= $a[0]; />` as a shorter version.
- I've marked the `fajrExecution` function as static, since that's how you were using it.

See https://eval.in/846061 for a demo.

Comment: thank you @iainn, i simplified the question, the exact question is as i edited, please take a look.